# How to change button title every time checkmark selected within custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a viewcontroller that has a tableview and a button at the bottom. Within each cell is a radio button as a tapGesture. I would like to updated the button with the number of cells selected. If my gesture is in the custom cell and my button is in my viewcontroller how can I get the two to work together?

Custom cell:

```
class SearchTalentCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var userProfileImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var talentUserName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var selectedImg: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var inviteSentImg: UIImageView!
var prospectRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
var currentTalent: UserType!

func setTalent(talent: UserType) {
    currentTalent = talent
    currentTalent.userKey = talent.userKey
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(selectTapped))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    selectedImg.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    selectedImg.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}


func configureCell(user: UserType, img: UIImage? = nil) {
    prospectRef = Cast.REF_PRE_PRODUCTION_CASTING_POSITION.child(ProjectDetailVC.currentProject).child(FIRDataCast.prospect.rawValue).child(CastingDetailVC.positionName).child(user.userKey)
    setTalent(talent: user)
    self.talentUserName.text = "\(user.firstName) \(user.lastName)"

    prospectRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let _ = snapshot.value as? NSNull {
            self.inviteSentImg.isHidden = true
        } else {
            self.inviteSentImg.image = UIImage(named: "inviteSent")
            self.inviteSentImg.isHidden = false
        }
    })
    if UserType.selectedTalentForSearch.contains(currentTalent.userKey) {
        selectedImg.image = UIImage(named: "radioSelected")

    } else {
        selectedImg.image = UIImage(named: "radioUnselected")

    }

    //Image Caching
    if img != nil {
        self.userProfileImage.image = img
    } else {

        if let imageURL = user.profileImage {

            let ref = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: imageURL)
            ref.data(withMaxSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("ZACK: Unable to download image from Firebase Storage")
                } else {
                    print("ZACK: Image downloaded from Firebase Storage")
                    if let imgData = data {
                        if let img = UIImage(data: imgData) {
                            self.userProfileImage.image = img
                            SearchTalentVC.userProfileImageCache.setObject(img, forKey: imageURL as NSString)
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}

@objc func selectTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    if UserType.selectedTalentForSearch.contains(currentTalent.userKey) {
        selectedImg.image = UIImage(named: "radioUnselected")
        UserType.selectedTalentForSearch = UserType.selectedTalentForSearch.filter{$0 != currentTalent.userKey}
        print("Keys: \(UserType.selectedTalentForSearch)")

    } else {
        selectedImg.image = UIImage(named: "radioSelected")
        UserType.selectedTalentForSearch.append(currentTalent.userKey)
        print("Keys: \(UserType.selectedTalentForSearch)")

    }
}
}
```

ViewController:

```
class SearchTalentVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var sendInviteButton: UIButton!
var searchingRole = [Cast]()
var unfilteredTalent = [UserType]()
var filteredTalent = [UserType]()
var selectedTalent = [UserType]()
var matchingTalentUserKeys = [String]()
var isFiltered = false
var selectedCounter = [String]()
var prospectRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
static var userProfileImageCache: NSCache<NSString, UIImage> = NSCache()
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Talent"
    searchController.searchBar.barStyle = .black
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    definesPresentationContext = true
    searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "Role Specific"]
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.sendInviteButton.setTitle("Send Invite to \(UserType.selectedTalentForSearch.count) Prospects", for: .normal)
    getTalentProfiles()

}
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using the cell selection inside the cell, as opposed to the tableview delegate function `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`?

If you use didSelectRowAt, you could have an array of selected rows and you can include the selectedRows.count into your button text.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Your cell seems to be digging into your data model to configure its appearance. So  UserType.selectedTalentForSearch seems to have in it the information to tell how many rows are selected and you should get it from there. A more common way to do this would be to have a delegate protocol so the cell notifies the view controller when it's tapped. The view controller updates the data model and the cell updates itself. The information would be passed into configureCell() if the cell is reloaded.